# Redirect 301 with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, parameters

I Want redirect URL with parameters, but doesn't work.

I have this code but doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^formul=register\.do$
RewriteRule ^peticion\.jsp$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

And I try this but fail, go to www.example.com/?formul=register.do

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /peticion.jsp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^formul=register.do$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

What I do is wrong?

Comment: the full url is http://www.example.com/peticion.jsp?formul=register.do and I want redirect to http://www.example.com

Comment: Your first attempt looks as if it should work. how did it fail?

Comment: It's solved, 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /peticion.jsp$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^formul=register.do$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.com/? [L,R=301]